# Convert desktop app to mobile app?

Tags: node.js, mobile, phonegap

Im trying convert desktop application to mobile app.Application is created with using HTML/CSS, Nodejs and electron framework.How can easily convert it?

Comment: You need to make sure your HTML is responsive (looks nice on mobile browsers) and then decide if you want to show it as a webpage or package it as an mobile application. For the latter try to search for something like 'hybrid html5 mobile app' and you will find a lot of frameworks that are like electron for mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Electron does't offer anyway to build into a mobile app but I suggest you look at NativeScript which allows you to build mobile apps using HTML CSS, JavaScript etc and it also has support for some frameworks like Angular. You may be able to port some of your current code into it.

https://www.nativescript.org/

Comment: Thanks for reply :).Im trying PhoneGap/Cordova its also build mobile apps using HTML CSS,JavaScript.But there is some problem I cant integrate nodejs 's require method.I tried requirjs its also doest work good :)

Answer (score 0):

That's where the good ol' noggin comes in my friend! Web development and mobile app development are two very different beasts. I suggest you invest some time into learning non-web based languages, such as objective-c, Swift, Python, etc.

Comment: Im a intern :) I never did front end developmnet or mobile app development.They just gave their desktop app and said make it work for android and ios :D

Comment: Well the best you can do right now @order66 is get Xcode for iOS and a Python IDE for android. For the front-end dev, I like W3Schools, they provide good documentation along with great examples. Web development and app development is not something you can master the first month. If you could, there wouldn't be a demand for software developers!

Comment: Thanks for reply and for advice :) @WebsitesOntario